# Ring?[when receiving a call]

Tags: android, sip

I'm preparing a SIP application, and want to add a ringing when just receiving a call, i built an alertdialog and want to add a tone. How can i make this ?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html